# Collapsing loops in a control-flow graph

Tags: graphs, compilers, data-flow-analysis

Let's say we are given some CFG, maybe in SSA-form, and we want to "collapse" each top-level loop into s single node, whose successors would be all exit blocks of the original loop. So we get an acyclic CFG with loops replaced by nodes.

I tried finding such a construction in the literature but without success.
Are there any references to such or a similar construction?